# Discrete polyhedral theory, reference request

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, finite-fields, discrete-optimization

When working in $\mathbb R^n$, there is a vast amount of literature on the study of solving $Ax=b$ as well as minimizing $c^T x$ subject to $Ax =b$. I'm thinking of Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition, Farkas's lemma, Caratheodory's theorem and all that kind of stuff. I'm wondering where to search for similar results with respect to solving/decomposing/optimizing over $Ax=b$ in finite fields.

Specifically, I am curious about methods on parallelizing solutions to systems of linear equations via decomposition techniques, rather than message-passing.

Comment: Your first sentence appears to be about about linear algebra, but your second sentence mentions theorems from linear programming. What is the analogue of $x\ge 0$ for finite fields?

Comment: Solving is still just linear algebra. But what do you mean by optimizing? If the components of $x$ and $c$ come from a finite field, then so do the values of $c^Tx$, and it is meaning less to say that one value would be larger than the other as finite fields don't have an order relation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen not necessarily, I am thinking of optimizing log likelihoods etc where the constraints are over finite fields.

Comment: @Rahul I'm not sure why you would require a perfect analogue, but if you insist: how about $x \geq 0$? :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "$\ge$" there. "An [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) necessarily has characteristic 0 since the elements 0 < 1 < 1 + 1 < 1 + 1 + 1 < ... necessarily are all distinct. Thus, an ordered field necessarily contains an infinite number of elements: a finite field cannot be ordered."

Comment: Ok, but then your objective function is not a linear function of $x$. My experience with this kind of stuff is rather limited. In coding theory applications you can be quite content with an algorithm, if it performs well in simulations even though you can't prove that it converges to the optimum:-) I once toyed with decoding algorithms for product codes using trellis representations for the factor codes. They parallelize well.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Actually at least in the binary case the LLR objective function is expressible as a linear function. I would assume the same is true for higher fields but I'm not certain.

Comment: @Rahul I don't see how the $x \geq 0$ matters really - simply put linear programs deals with constraint sets of the type $a_i^T x = b_i$, I'm interested in constraint sets of the type $a_i^T x = b_i $ mod $ q$.

Comment: The constraint $Ax=b$ only defines an affine set and can be described using linear algebra alone; it does not involve any of the linear programming theorems you mentioned. You don't get polyhedra or linear programming until you add linear *inequalities*, of which $Ax=b \wedge x\ge0$ is a standard form.

Comment: LLR isn't linear even in the binary case. Remember that arithmetic with elements $0$ and $1$ of $\Bbb{F}_2$ is totally different from the arithmetic with real numbers $0$ and $1$.

Comment: The sum of LLR:s can indeed be *expressed* as a linear function. See https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wainwrig/Papers/FelWaiKar05.pdf to see how